# XMLBeanDefinitionStoreException: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying the following code: http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-with-hibernate-crud-example.html#.Uus0bvnoSGc
the sdnext-servlet.xml is as follows

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xsi:schemalocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties">
</context:property-placeholder>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava">
</context:component-scan>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager">
</tx:annotation-driven>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="jspViewResolver">
 <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
 <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
 <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
 <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
 <property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
   <value>com.dineshonjava.model.Employee</value>
  </list>
 </property>
 <property name="hibernateProperties">
 <props>
  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>    
        </props>
      </property>
</bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="hibernateTransactionManager">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

I am getting the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 62; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the xml namespace definition to this

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
```

and it should work

The problem is with your definition of `xsi:schemalocation` the typo is with the `L` It is supposed to be capital, only then would it recognise the tag.

Comment: And what have you changed?

Comment: I used the xml namespace definitions as suggested, but the error did not go away. Still an exception at the last line of the namespace definition

Comment: Edited the answer with the explanation to your problem. There is a typo with the `schemaLocation`

Comment: I got the same error and i also changed in the xml file but not working.

Comment: create a different question and post it on SO. There would be someone who would answer it for you.

Comment: I also had a similar error; however, I did not specify the correct *.xsd. Thank you for this!

Comment: you just saved my day !

Answer (score 4):

This is far fetched, but it might happen to someone else as it did to me.

I was packing a fat-jar with the `maven-assembly-plugin` and got the `XMLBeanDefinitionStoreException` when trying to execute my main class. The plugin was configured as follows:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.bigcompany.module.MyMainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> this is used for inheritance merges
            <phase>package</phase> bind to the packaging phase
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The solution for me was packing with a different plug-in: the `maven-shade-plugin`. The configuration is the following:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.bigcompany.module.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <!-- configures the suffix name for the executable jar here it will be '<project.artifact>-<project.version>-executable.jar' -->
                    <shadedClassifierName>executable</shadedClassifierName>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The resulting jar did execute without exception using the same command line that raised the exception with the jar generated with the other plug-in.

Comment: @cm12 that was the point. Now that it has helped, the answer was worth writing.

Comment: That was exactly the problem by me. It's a pity that maven-assembly-plugin doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Need to change the default namespace like below:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dewsoftware.webapp" />

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

change namespace:`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">`